# Do Python lists hold pointers or always absolute values?

Tags: python, list

I want to know weather Python lists can hold pointers to varisbles.

Consider this example:

```
regsiters = {"rax":64,"rbx":0}
RAM = [0,0,0,0]
RAM[1] = registers["rax"]
```

Does `RAM[1]` hold the value `64` or a pointer to `registers["rax"]`?

And if instead of the dictionary `regsiters` there was a variable with the same value, would the same be true?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I have searched stackoverflow for answers, and although I haven't found anything my searching skills are suboptimal at best. I am sorry if this is a duplicate.

Comment: A good read: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: There's no concept of pointers on python (at least within my limited knowledge).

Comment: [why not simply try it out?](https://repl.it/repls/HideousColdDeclarations)

Comment: @Ilja Everilä Thanks so much! That solved my problem

Comment: There's got to be a duplicate?

Comment: And @Ev. Kounis I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks so much.

Comment: @timgeb I expect so but I can't find one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
registers = {"rax":64,"rbx":0}
RAM = [0,0,0,0]

RAM[1] = registers["rax"]

print("before modifying")
print(RAM)
print(registers)

registers["rax"] = 20

print("after modifying")
print(RAM)
print(registers)
```

Output <<

```
before modifying
[0, 64, 0, 0]
{'rax': 64, 'rbx': 0}
after modifying
[0, 64, 0, 0]
{'rax': 20, 'rbx': 0}
```

Results should be self-explanatory.

Comment: This solves my problem too. Will accept in a minute when stackoverflow lets me. Thanks!